# Is it possible to retrieve the user token in an app, after migrating an app from swift to react native?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, oauth, react-native

We have an existing app written in Swift where the logged in user has their oAuth token stored in the app.

The app is now being redeveloped in React Native. If we release the app as a new version of the app in the App Store, when a user upgrades and installs the new version, can we get hold of the user token even though the app is completely differently architected?

Answer (score 1):

Application will be "the same" until you update app id regardless of technology. So you can access all data saved by native application. Where are you keeping this token?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not the developer and am not familiar with Swift apps. I can see from the code it stores it using a namespace called `AuthSession.sharedSession`. I'm not sure if this using a standard library or not.

Comment: I think it is your app class. If app saves token with `UserDefaults` on low level then you can use this built-in module to read value in react-native http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.44/docs/settings.html#settings I didn't use it before but it should works.

Comment: @farwayer what if Auth token is stored in keychain? I just came across one react native library, that helps in fetching data stored in keychain...Here it is https://github.com/mcodex/react-native-sensitive-info

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Native Module that reads the value from the native application and passes it to React Native.

More information about Native Modules for iOS here: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html